# how do we fax 15,000 pages per day on 10-20 lines?

Tags: fax

can anyone recommend a cheap faxing solution? we already have the lines we just need a way to fax

we will need to fax to about 500 - 1500 different lines about 15,000 pages. so about 5-10 pages per destination

Comment: Do the documents need to be scanned, or are they already electronic? What hardware do you already have? Are these POTS lines, or part of a T1? Can you answer these, and provide any other information about your environment that is relevant? Because otherwise, I'd tell you to get 10-20 fax machines and some highschool workstudy kids.

Comment: we have a T1, the documents currently need to be scanned . we have like 10 fax servers already

Comment: I'm not helping you if it means I'll be receiving one of those mass vacation faxes...

Comment: @greg you mean you dont want a totally free 10 day all inclusive cruise to south africa?

Comment: @|__:  I'd rather take that Carnival cruise stranded off the coast of San Diego...

Comment: @greg what is |__?

Comment: @|__: It's your username..

Comment: @paus please dont call me that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GFI Faxmaker has worked well for my company, pretty hands off after the initial setup. They offer a free trial on their website.

Comment: Even though I see this already selected as the answer, I'd like to second this - I've used GFI FaxMaker with great success. I've found it's easier to manage than the Esker solution. Also, I highly recommend the Brooktrout cards for faxing - they have T1 models. Spendy but well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Esker VSIfax](http://www.esker.com/solutions/fax_servers/solutions/fax_software_unix.asp) running on Windows or Linux. I've used it in plenty production scenarios and it's incredibly robust. Usually, I'd back it with multiple external Multitech modems, Digi RAS cards or go the T1 route with a Brooktrout board. There's also an option to offload your physical fax lines and Fax-over-IP to Esker's data centers...

Answer (score 1):

[RightFax](http://faxsolutions.opentext.com/fax-server.aspx) is a popular and functional solution. I believe it even supports T1 connections.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an obvious one but have you considered email instead of faxes? it's...well...less ghetto/80's.

Also, as a rule, this site doesn't support people in building spamming solutions, can you explain why you need to do this please otherwise we reserve the right to delete your question.

Comment: Wow..totally uncool..

Comment: @|__:  I've now voted to close your question as too localized based on your unnecessary comment here...

Comment: I wasn't presuming anything - I simply asked you to explain yourself when we do routinely get asked questions by wannabe-spammers - and you've done this thank you.

Comment: @chopper you are legally not allowed to email medical records.

Comment: @I__, it is your responsibility as the person asking the question to provide us with useful details.  If you ask for something unusual, then you should expect to explain why, instead of being a jerk when someone suggests alternatives.

Comment: @|__:  If you expect help in the future, you might want to tone down the attitude.  Just sayin'...

Comment: I assume that |_ wrote something ill-considered and then deleted it?

Comment: @mfinni:  He did indeed

Comment: @finnigan im also from new haven btw

Comment: @GregD: I assume your "totally uncool" comment was directed at the deleted comment? Now it looks like it's directed at Chopper3's answer.

Comment: not a problem dennis, greg and I discussed this Q offline.